# Bootstrap panels within Thymeleaf loop - same id and href

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, frontend, thymeleaf

I'm trying to generate bootstrap collapse panels within Thymeleaf loop, like that:

```
<table>
  <tr th:each="p, iterStat : ${completedList}">
    <td style="padding: 0 15px 0 15px;">
      <div class="panel panel-success">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"
               href="#collapseOne" th:text="${p.key}">p.k</a>
            <span style="float: right;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div th:id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <span th:text="${p.value}"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But I have the same `id` and `href` for every element of the loop so the panels doesn't works.

Can I do something to change dynamically `id` and `href`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *status variable* (`iterStat`) to create a unique id for every row:

```xml
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" th:href="'#collapse' + ${iterStat.index}" th:text="${p.key}">
```

and

```
<div th:id="'collapse' + ${iterStat.index}" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this same issue and what I did was

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample"
                            th:each="todo : ${todos}">
                            <div class="accordion-item">
                                <h2 class="accordion-header" th:id="heading + ${todo.id}">
                                    <button class="accordion-button" type="button"
                                        data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                                        th:attr="data-bs-target=|#col${todo.id}" aria-expanded="true"
                                        aria-controls="collapseOne">Accordion Item #1</button>
                                </h2>
                                <div th:id="col + ${todo.id}"
                                    class="accordion-collapse collapse show"
                                    th:attr="aria-labelledby=|heading${todo.id}|"
                                    data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
                                    <div class="accordion-body">
                                        <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It
                                        is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the
                                        appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These
                                        classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing
                                        and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this
                                        with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also
                                        worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the
                                        <code>.accordion-body</code>
                                        , though the transition does limit overflow.
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

instead of concatenating the id, just add it as a string with the `th:attr`, then the value should be put inside the `| {dynamic value e.g id, uuid, primary key} |`.
then concatenate with the `+` for the `th:id` which will automatically know its equivalent attribute as set earlier.