# Thymeleaf-How to bind click event on div inside th:each loop

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I am using thymeleaf foreach loop to traverse my data.
The problem is that since it is in the foreach loop, all the div have the same id which is "delDiv". And when I click on it, it will always show the first div.

```
  <div id="delDiv" sec:authorize="hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')">
                                    <input type="hidden" id="resultId" th:value="${result.getId()}">
                                    <i class="fa fa-trash deleteBadge"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="timeDiv" style="" th:text="${result.getUpdatedAt()}"></div>
```

I want to have different on clicks for each new div created by foreach loop.
This is how i am generating new row using foreach thymeleaf

```
   <div class="row" th:each="result:${recog}"> My above code is inside this
</div
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You should uniquely differentiate between your divs by adding an **index** to the div id as follows (just use Thymeleaf loop helpers for this):

```
<div class="row" th:each="result, iterHelper :${recog}">
 <div id="'delDiv__${iterHelper.index}__'" sec:authorize="hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')">
  <input type="hidden" id="resultId" th:value="${result.getId()}"><i class="fa fa-trash deleteBadge"></i></div><div class="timeDiv" style="" th:text="${result.getUpdatedAt()}"></div>
</div
```

Please follow [this](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#iteration) for further details. Especially Section 6.2

Comment: By the way another example for this case is answered in this SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45114891/bootstrap-panels-within-thymeleaf-loop-same-id-and-href

Comment: Thank you for your help.